# Unable to transfer ERC20 tokens from a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, truffle-test, revert-opcode

I'm having trouble getting a solidity contract method to transfer ERC20 tokens from address A to B assuming B has called `approve` outside the contract and setup sufficient `allowance` for A. The `allowance` value prints fine inside the contract but the `transferFrom` fails. I'm missing something in how the ownership and signatures are set up. I do have a workaround where the same `transferFrom` works outside the contract but I'd like to do it inside.

I set up a sample repo with truffle tests and an issue to describe the problem further:

https://github.com/PulseBlockchain/oz-sample-app/issues/1

This is an excerpt from a larger project where I have a similar problem.

It looks similar to this question, [ERC20 approve and transferFrom from a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41827/erc20-approve-and-transferfrom-from-a-contract), except I'm doing `approve` outside and want the contract to just do `transferFrom`. It looks like there is a way to do `transfer` from a contract like this Open Zeppelin `CrowdSale` contract [does](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/e1dc1411fc154970216eb7ccc3855b1052f81889/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol#L150) and which I have working in my project. I like to be able to do either `transfer` or `transferFrom` from my own contract and like to better understand ownership and signature rules around it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved thanks to debugging assistance from [Gonçalo Sá](https://github.com/GNSPS). Here is the fix [commit](https://github.com/PulseBlockchain/oz-sample-app/commit/2948b5b3a5c18641ea79d975a9863debb1ce8005)
tl;dr: you have to `approve` the `allowance` first to the address of the contract calling `tranferFrom` and then transfer the value to the final destination address.

Answer (score 0):

You could be suffering from the batch overflow bug. https://medium.com/@TokPie/erc20-tokens-under-attack-from-new-batchoverflow-bug-while-tokpie-remains-safe-b59dd716d469